# Microservices Implementation in Mysql (Relational database structure)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, relational-database, microservices

We have an existing project build with Mysql and Java struts. We have to implement the new section(Let's say a CRM) in the project. The current project project we are having Mysql database and it is having around 160 tables and all these tables having connection between each other (Foreign Key relations).

The new Project we are planning to implement using Spring boot Microservices, and on using this with the existing database we are facing some issue on structuring microservices our application.

When we are proceeding with microservices we have two options to manage entities

1. Keep the entity and all the DAO's as a seperate Microservices(Entity Microservice) this will communicate with all microservices. In this case the advantage is that, if we have any change in the database structure or field change we only needs to change this  Entity  microservices since this is using by all the microservices we can manage the entity for the project from a single area
2. We can manage the entities that needed in each microservices in each microservices package itself. But in that case the advantage is that any of the microservices will not have any connection and each microservice will act as independently. But the problem is that when we have a change in(say doctor table) this entity change we have to update in each miccroservices.

Let us know if we have any other project structure that we can use in our project since our database is in mysql and each tables are tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new commons package that contains only entity, dto and util classes.

Now make this commons project as dependency jar in all of your microservices project.

Finally, there's no use to initiate commons project as microservice. To deploy a new microservice that needs commons jar as dependency then make sure you first clone the commons repository and respective repository.